# Approximately find $2.05^{3.03}$ using differential calculus

Tags: real-analysis

It should be done without micro calculator.
Let $$f(x,y) = x^y$$
Then $$f(x_0+\Delta x, y_0+\Delta y) \approx f(x_0, y_0) + d[f(x,y)]\Bigg|_{x=x_0, y=y_0}$$
So we got $$f(x_0+\Delta x, y_0+\Delta y) \approx f(x_0, y_0)+y_0x_0^{y_0-1}\Delta x+x_0^{y_0}\ln x_0 \Delta y = 8+0.6+0.24\ln 2$$
Where $x_0=2, y_0=3, \Delta x = 0.05, \Delta y = 0.03$

But how to find approximate value of $\ln 2$?

Comment: Since you're doing approximations anyway, I would assume you're allowed to _remember_ that $\log 2 \approx 0.7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...$$

So,
$$\ln(2)=\ln(1+1)=1-1/2+1/3-1/4+...$$
You might need to calculate it for a couple of terms, till $1/n$ becomes neglegible. Since you're having a microcalculator, the calculation should be easier (it becomes quite accurate after $10$ terms)

Comment: I am not sure it is possible without calculator. It should be done 100 times at least to reach 0,01 accuracy

Comment: Yeah a calculator would be better. But since it you were asking for approximating it, this method would be legit. Expanding upto $10$ terms gives a pretty accurate value.

Comment: @danielleontiev I didn't realise you had a micro calculator, in that case wouldn't this calculation be easier?

Comment: A common way to accelerate the convergence would be, for example, to write $\ln 2 = \ln (4/3) - \ln (2/3)$ and then use the series for $\ln(1+x)$ with $x = \pm \frac{1}{3}$ to evaluate the two terms.  (And in fact, you could use $\ln(1+x) - \ln(1-x) = 2x + \frac{2}{3} x^3 + \frac{2}{5} x^5 + \cdots$.)

Comment: The salt is to find the value without calculator, so, I try to find the way that can be done quite fast on paper

Comment: @danielleontiev yeah, daniel schelpler's is an easy method. Another easy method would be to remember the convertion factor between base $e$ and base $10$, and remember the values of $\log_{10}2,\log_{10}3,\log_{10}5$ because most of the other logarithms to base $10$ can be approximated by a good amount using these $3$ logarithms (for ex: $\log_{10}50 \approx \log_{10}49 = 2\log_{10}7 \approx 2\log_{10}6 = 2(\log_{10}2+\log_{10}3)$